# rails active record cannot save timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I want to choose a datetime and save it by active record in Rails.

Here's code.

```
@match = Match.new
dating_datetime = rand(5.hours).seconds.since.to_datetime.in_time_zone(8)
@match.dating_datetime = dating_datetime
@match.save
```

And I want it to save in timezone(8), but when I use rails console to check, the value I saved is in timezone UTC '2018-03-24 11:06:14', But I am in timezone 8 '2018-03-24 19:06:10'

[image]

Also, I've added these in application.rb, but nothing changed.

```
config.time_zone = 'Taipei'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Is it possible to save datetime with timezone to table by Rails active record?

Comment: Datetime is always saved in utc in the database (at least in Postgres). The timezone in rails is just for localization (display) purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is as @Iceman mentioned in comment

---

Datetime is always saved in utc in the database (at least in Postgres). The timezone in rails is just for localization (display) purposes.

---

why don't check it with `record.dating_datetime` in your console, it will give datetime in your server configured timezone.